# Creating New Matching Logic in Informatica (Ratcliffe - Obershelp)

Tags: matching, string-matching, informatica, jaro-winkler

I am conducting a matching project in Informatica 10.2.1 wherein I need to identify matching strings within product descriptions. Ratcliffe-Obershelp is the matching strategy I need to implement.

I've heard Ratcliffe-Obershelp yields greater results than Jaro - Winkler but I am not sure how to code this into a transformation in Informatica since it is not built in.

No code to show as I don't even know where to start.

I'd expect this to be a transformation/group of transformations that would reproduce the matching score that Ratcliffe-Obershelp creates on a per-line basis.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the matching logic performs operations in a loop iterating over the input strings. It is not possible to implement such "loop over string" in Expression Transformation using built-in functions. I see two options:

- create `DECODE` function with multiple conditions for each possible length. - This will be ugly. And can be possible assuming only that we start at the begining of each string - implementing full substring comparison will be... so ugly I can't imagine :)
- use Java Transformation - as much as I have putting Java into mappings, there are some cases where it's justified. This look like one of the few. Here's some [JS reference](https://github.com/GitSage/gestalt-pattern-matcher/blob/master/gestalt-pattern-matcher.js)